# Laravel Relationships recursive

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship, laravel-5

I have 3 Models:

City:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'code', 'country_id', 'status', 'weather_code',
];

public function translations() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CityTranslation');

}

public function country() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Country');

}
```

CityTranslation

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'lang', 'city_id',
];

public function city() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\City', 'id', 'city_id');
}
```

and Country

```
protected $fillable = [
    'code', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'currency_id', 'timezone', 'dam_date', 'status',
];

public function city() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');

}
```

My problem is when a go through my CityTranslations and display the city name for the selected language i want also to show information about the city and its country.

There is no problem to call $cityTranslation->city->longitude, but when i call $cityTranslation->city->country->code it gives me a MySQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries.city_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `countries` where `countries`.`city_id` = 4439 and `countries`.`city_id` is not null)
```

How can I make recursive relations?

Comment: Why do you have One-to-Many between cities and countries? One city can have multiple countries? oO It tries to find city_id in country because of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$cityTranslation = \App\CityTranslation::with('city.country')->get();
```

Thats if you want to get all city Translation and it related city and country. The you can loop through and get the country code.

if you want to pick only one city Translation and it related item you can do

```
$cityTranslation = \App\CityTranslation::with('city.country')->find($id);
```

Change this (in your city model)

```
public function country() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Country');

}
```

to

```
public function country() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country');

}
```

Because country can have many cities and every city must belong to a country

Comment: Thanks oseintow, it works as i wish, but if i go to the city form i get one error, unfortunately i do not know how to find our where is the problem: BadMethodCallException in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php line 2161: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::city()

Comment: i have found the problem. Actually only the change of the country() method in the City model to belongsTo was enought :)